# Sharekit image uploading

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, sharekit

Please help with the problem for uploading the screenshot photo through Sharekit:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(parentPreviewImageView.frame.size);
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(previewImageView.frame.size);

[self.parentPreviewView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageCopy, self, nil, nil);
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageCopy, self, @selector(imageSavedToPhotosAlbum:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

How should I combine the codes above to the following line?
Thanks a lot.

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:screenshot.image title:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:screenshot.image title:@""];
```

**Do:**

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:imageCopy title:@""];
```

In your code I don't see any screenshot variable so I am expecting this is just a wrong variable issue.

Comment: Maybe I haven't stated clearly, my app is for photo editing by adding overlay mask on top of selected image. Right now I can only choose either the overlay mask as a photo to share, or the selected image to share. I wonder how can I combine the merged image and share it on facebook. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a screenshot of the overlay mask on the image. I'm sure it's not the best way but it's the easiest.